# Selection Rate in selection_rate_group_summary in fairlearn

Tags: fairlearn

How does selection_rate_group_summary decide the cutoff value when we pass the output of a mitigated model to it in fairlearn module.

The selection rate in one of our data is really high all the time while using the function which is unnatural.

Answer (score 0):

There is no cutoff value. `selection_rate_group_summary` simply collects selection rates for all groups and overall.

Example:

```py
>>> from fairlearn.metrics import selection_rate_group_summary
>>> y = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> sensitive_features = ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
>>> selection_rate_group_summary(y, y, sensitive_features=sensitive_features)
{'overall': 0.875, 'by_group': {'a': 0.75, 'b': 1.0}}
```

Similarly, if we have lots and lots of samples and the numbers get very large, this still works (no cutoff):

```
>>> y = [1] * 1000000
>>> y[0] = 0
>>> sensitive_features = ["a", "b"] * 500000
>>> selection_rate_group_summary(y, y, sensitive_features=sensitive_features)
{'overall': 0.999999, 'by_group': {'a': 0.999998, 'b': 1.0}}
```

If you meant something else please update the question or write a message to the community on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/fairlearn/community)

Comment: Well Gitter is blocked by my company for suspected malware, this is the only solution. What I meant was, how does the mitigated model chose 1/0, now in know the answer looking at code

Comment: If you meant the Gitter desktop app, there's also a website you can open in the browser.
Let me know if anything else is unclear. I'm not sure this helped...